# Не добавляется часть записей в FireBase(Java)

Tags: база-данных, строки, auth, firebase

Есть некая база FireBase Real-time Database.

EmainAuth.java

```
private void writeNewUser(String userId, String email) {
    // TODO FIX BUG: CANNOT SEND AN EMAIL TO FIREBASE DB
    Log.d(TAG, "Email in writeNewUser(): " + email);
    UserAccount user = new UserAccount(email);
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase.child("Users").child(userId).setValue(user);
}
```

UserAccount.java

```
import android.util.Log;

public class UserAccount {

public final static String TAG = "tag";

String username;
int rating;
String email;

public UserAccount(){}

public UserAccount(String email){
    // TODO CHECK WHAT'S WRONG- EMAIL COULD BE EMPTY
    Log.d(TAG, "Email is UserAccount constructor: " + email);
    this.email = email;
    this.rating = 1;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public int getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public void setRating(int rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}
}
```

Что выводится в консоль:

*Email in writeNewUser(): jxgdiy@idgdgu.hx*

*Email is UserAccount constructor: jxgdiy@idgdgu.hx*

А в итоге, в базу данных попадает только это:

```
{
  "Users" : {
        "G5bIG92W4sS3XFtdKFqAUVGAfm43" : {
             "rating" : 1
                 }
            }
}
```

Куда пропадает поле email? И вообще, раньше было необходимо отправить 2 строчки, и они обе на отправлялись. Как сделать так, чтобы строчки появлялись в Firebase Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто. Чтобы Firebase DB могла без проблем оперировать обьектами класса вам нужно указывать геттер и сеттер для каждого поля, потому что только так Firebase DB может взаимодействовать с полями вашего класса. В Вашем случае конкретно, нехватает геттера чтобы получить email. А если бы вы записывали данные в обьект то уже понадобиться сеттер. Поэтому советую добавить сразу и геттер и сеттер.

Еще дополнение на будующее, чтобы игнорировать поле у которого есть геттер и сеттер нужно дописать аннотацию `@Ignore`.

Почитать подробно можно [здесь](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).

Comment: Большое спасибо! По своей невнимательности пропустил эту строчку: "Pass a custom Java object, if the class that defines it has a default constructor that takes no arguments and has public getters for the properties to be assigned.", хотя не раз перечитывал)

Comment: Ещё один вопрос. Важно ли, чтобы тот пустой конструктор, необходимый для записи объекта, не содержал в себе никакого кода?

Comment: Нет не важно, я проверял. С кодом тоже все работает.